# Javascript code not being called on pageload? .net

Tags: javascript, .net

I am currently trying to call a JavaScript function when the update panel refreshes, but for some reason it is just not being called; even though I am using the exact same method which is working for other functions.

c#, this is in the page load event:

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
                  UpdatePanel1,
                   this.GetType(),
                   "Modify Map",
                   "modifyMap();",
                   true);
```

Javascript function:

```
function modifyMap() {
            alert(1);
            //To change the map size if the user is viewing the site on a mobile.
            if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
                //Change width/height of map.         

                //Change the width of the wrapper to 100% of the screen.
                document.getElementById('wrapper-div').style.width = "100%";
                //Set the map to fill the wrapper.
                document.getElementById('canvasMap').style.width = "100%";
                //Set the height of the map.
                document.getElementById('canvasMap').style.height = "500px";
            }

        }
```

If anyone could help me out that would be great.

Thanks,

Callum

Answer (score 1):

Add an onload event such as:

```
 window.onload = modifyMap;
```

Do not put it inside a function.  I always put it right before the script close tag `</script>`

You could also add the onload event to an HTML tag.

```
<body onload="modifyMap()">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to register the script in the PreRender, also try renaming the key without a space.

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
                  UpdatePanel1,
                   this.GetType(),
                   "ModifyMapKey",
                   "modifyMap();",
                   true);
}
```